# How to start publishing Flash games

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, publishing

I'm already pretty adept at AS3 and all, and I have plenty of ideas for Flash games that I want to start making. However, I was wondering, when I've made my first one, how should I publish it, and how can I make it popular? I will upload it on my own website, but should I upload it to a more well-known site? And if so, which do you recommended? (Armor Games, Kongregate, etc.)

Comment: Why choose? Why not try to push it to as many websites as possible?

Comment: Worry about finishing a game before worrying about how to make it popular.  A good game will spread like wildfire regardless of placement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to push to as many websites as possible. http://www.mochimedia.com/ is a great resources for learning about developing, publishing, and monetizing flash games.

If you are interested in getting a sponsor and making some money I definitely recommend you check out http://www.flashgamelicense.com/ . I used them in the pass and got a sponsor to pay me $4,000.00 for my flash game. Back when I used them they recommended that you give 10% to Flash Game License if they helped you with getting a sponsor (yes it's a recommendation, I ended up giving them 10%).

Good luck!

Comment: FGL now requires developers to give them a percentage, but it's well worth it if you don't have connections to sponsors yet.

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I figured to put it on multiple websites, but I was just curious as to what people recommended. I'll have a look at FGL too.

Answer (score -1):

First think of a great idea that you think would really get ppl glued to your game. Then think of how good of an artwork you could implement in your game to make it more cooler and attractive. Finally when you're done with the game, look for sites that allow you to post your game and then just publish it. If your game is good enough, you'll attract sponsors.